# algorithm to compress a string

Tags: javascript, algorithm, compression

I want to write a function to compress the characters of a string such as 'bbbab' would be converted to 'b3ab' and I'm getting stuck

it's only printing "b3"

here's the code so far

```js
let string = 'bbbab';
let letters = string.split("");
let currentAlphabetLetter = letters[0];
let count = 0;
let newString = [];

string.split("").forEach(letter => {
    if (letter === currentAlphabetLetter) {
        count++;
    } else {
        if (count > 0) {
            newString.push(`${currentAlphabetLetter}${count}`);
        } else {
        newString.push(`${letter}`);
    }
    count = 0;
    currentAlphabetLetter = letter;
  }
})


console.log(newString);
```

Comment: *"and I'm getting stuck"* You have to provide more information about your problem than that. How exactly are you stuck? Do you get an error? Does your code not produce the output you expect? Which output do you get? Which do you expect? What is the input? Please see [ask].

Comment: Where do you get stuck?

Comment: It's only printing or adding rather, b3 to the array

Answer (score 1):

When you start a new letter, you need to set `count` to `1`, otherwise you're not counting the first occurrence of the character.

This isn't a problem at the very beginning of the string, because you process the first letter twice: you extract it with `let currentAlphabetLetter = letters[0];` and then process it again on the first iteration of the `forEach`. To make the beginning of the string the same as other occurrences, you should iterate over the substring starting with the 2nd character.

And rather than pushing onto an array, you should append to a string.

When `count` is `1` you need to append `currentAlphabetLetter`, not `letter`.

```js
let string = 'bbbab';
let letters = string.split("");
let currentAlphabetLetter = letters[0];
let count = 1;
let newString = "";

string.substr(1).split("").forEach(letter => {
  if (letter === currentAlphabetLetter) {
    count++;
  } else {
    if (count > 1) {
      newString += `${currentAlphabetLetter}${count}`;
    } else {
      newString += `${currentAlphabetLetter}`;
    }
    count = 1;
    currentAlphabetLetter = letter;
  }
});

// Process the last letter
if (count > 1) {
  newString += `${currentAlphabetLetter}${count}`;
} else {
  newString += `${currentAlphabetLetter}`;
}

console.log(newString);
```

Answer (score 1):

You  may do as follows;

```js
var str = 'bbbabccc',
    res = [...str].reduce((r,c,i) => (r[r.length-1][0] === c || !i) ? (r[r.length-1] += c, r)
                                                                    : r.concat(c), [""])
                  .reduce((r,s) => r + s[0] + (s.length-1 ? s.length : ""), "");
console.log(res);
```

We have two `.reduce()`s cascaded here but first it's good to know that `[...str]` turns into `["b", "b", "b", "a", "b", "c", "c", "c"]`.

The first `.reduce()` will reduce it to an array of strings such as `["bbb", "a", "b", "ccc"]`.

The second `.reduce()` will further reduce it to the result. The inner mechanics of each reducers are for you to solve.

However, as hint, keep in mind that the comma operator `,` as in `(r[r.length-1] += c, r)` takes the last element of `r` array (accumulator here) adds `c` to the end of it and returns `r`.

Comment: can you explain this better?

Comment: @totalnoob I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Like this should work for you

```
let string = 'bbbab';
let newString = [];

if (string.length < 2) { console.log(string); }
else {
    let letters = string.split("");
    let prev = letters[0];
    let count = 1;
    for( var i = 1; i < letters.length; i++) {
      if (letters[i] !== prev) {
        count > 1 ? newString.push(`${prev}${count}`) : newString.push(`${prev}`);
        count = 1;
      } else {
        count++;
      }
      prev = letters[i];
    }
    /* last element push */
    count > 1 ? newString.push(`${prev}${count}`) : newString.push(`${prev}`);
    console.log(newString.join(""));
}
```